# Passing a function with parameters as an argument to another function in R

Tags: r, function

Consider an example:

I want to pass a function with or without parameters to another function and use it in the following way:

```
genfx <- function(fx, fy, M, fs, ...){ 

  a <- 1
  b <- fx(a)
  ...
}
```

When `fx = dunif` it works, but how can I pass additional parameters for `fx`, for example, `dunif(min=-0.5, max-0.5)`)? Is it possible to do it without specifying additional set of parameters to `genfx`?

Answer (score 5):

Without more specifics, and we may not need them, the simplest case is just to insert `...` into the call to `fx`, as if the `...` were just another argument:

```
genfx <- function(fx, fy, M, fs, ...){ 

  a <- 1
  b <- fx(a, ...)
  ## more code here
}
```

E.g.:

```
genfx <- function(fx, ...){ 

  a <- 1
  b <- fx(a, ...)
  b
}

> genfx(dunif)
[1] 1
> genfx(dunif, min = -0.5, max = 1.5)
[1] 0.5
```

(Note I removed the other arguments for simplicity in the example. This wasn't necessary though in this case.)

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way with `pryr` package

```
library(pryr)

genfx <- function(fx) { 
    a <- 1
    b <- fx(a)
    b
}

myDunif <- partial(dunif, min=-0.5, max=0.5)

genfx(dunif)
[1] 1
genfx(myDunif)
[1] 0
```

`partial` just prepares a function with partially complete list of arguments. Handy in situations like this.